# pgu setup.py installation traceback error

Tags: python, installation, pygame, pgu

I am having trouble running the pgu setup.py installation file on my Mac. The error I get when I run the file in IDLE is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Developer/Python/pgu-0.18/setup.py", line 72, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Developer/Python/pgu-0.18/setup.py", line 69, in main
    setup(**setup_args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 140, in setup
    raise SystemExit, gen_usage(dist.script_name) + "\nerror: %s" % msg
SystemExit: usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: no commands supplied
```

I am having trouble interpreting what the errors mean. Thanks.

I realize now that I'm supposed to run:

```
python setup.py install
```

However, I am running on a Mac. Running that piece of script in the terminal gives an error of not finding the file.

Comment: I just ran the setup.py file with no other commands.

Comment: Then that's what the error says: you need to add a command. Run `setup.py --help-commands` and add a command that you wish to run (`setup.py <command here>`).

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to python and pygame, but what command should I run to extract the pgu library?

Comment: In most cases `python setup.py install` is all you need. If pgu does not require any custom installation then that command should be fine.

Comment: I tried running the command in terminal but it gave this error: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'setup.py'

Comment: Did you run the command in the terminal at the same location where the file `setup.py` exists? Can you edit your question to show the terminal commands you tried and the copy-pasted output from the terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
svn checkout http://pgu.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ pgu
cd pgu
**python setup.py install**
```